# SharePoint 2010 event listener - SPItemEventReceiver with multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an event handler dll that implements `SPItemEventReceiver`.  I like to run a background thread in this dll.  The events are passed on to this background thread for processing so that the event handling methods won't block.  SharePoint 2010 loads the dll but the thread does not start.  I am not able to use the `ThreadPool` class as well.  Is this a restriction imposed by SharePoint on external event handlers?  How can I work around this?

Comment: There's no restriction at the SharePoint-level, assuming you're not running as a sandboxed solution. Can you post the code?

Comment: i don't think this is necessary, as each event receiver is run asynchronously from the request that initiated the event.  basically, i believe they are already background threads.  in other words long processing in an event receiver, i don't think, will block the next one from firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using 'post' events (ItemAdded, ItemUpdated), then you just have to register them as asynchronous mode. Then the event handler's events will run in their own threads, not blocking.

Beware of race conditions between your event handler and displaying your edit form (i.e. that your event handler updates your item after the edit form has been displayed).

```
SPEventReceiverDefinition eventReceiver = eventReceivers.Add();
eventReceiver.Name = receiverName;
eventReceiver.Synchronization = SPEventReceiverSynchronization.Asynchronous; 
eventReceiver.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
eventReceiver.SequenceNumber = sequenceNumber; 
eventReceiver.Assembly = assemblyFullName ;
eventReceiver.Class = assemblyClassName ;
eventReceiver.Data = receiverData ;

eventReceiver.Update();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverdefinition.synchronization.aspx